Closed 3-Manifolds Without Anosov Flows
It is known that if a closed 3-manifold admits an Anosov flow, then its fundamental group grows exponentially.
Is there a counterexample  for the converse? A closed 3-manifold with fundamental group of exponential growth, that does not admit any Anosov flow?

The connect sum of two closed 3-manifolds will have fundamental group a free product, which almost always contains a nonabelian free subgroup and thus has exponential growth. Maybe connect-sums of two manifolds that do not themselves admit Anosov flows like connect-sums of two lens spaces or two copies of $S^2 \times S^1$ could give counterexamples?

The stable or unstable foliation of an Anosov flow is a  Reebless foliation. There are hyperbolic 3-manifolds without Reebless foliations, hence without Anosov flows and with exponential growth of the fundamental group. https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-03-00426-0

That’s great. Thank you!
